How to open/utilize Oracle Developer Tools inside Visual Studio after installing it?
I feel like quite the novice asking such a simple question but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to open/utilize Oracle Developer Tools inside Visual Studio. I see no difference in the Visual Studio UI post-download, and I see nowhere to use these new tools. I have confirmed ODT is in my extension downloads list. ODT version 21.11.0.0 if that matters.
Any help is appreciated.
I've downloaded ODT from the extension marketplace, I was expecting a window or tab or something to appear within visual studio post-download. Can't find anything ODT-related.

Which IDE are you really using, because you tagged this with "visual studio" and "visual studio code", and those refer to 2 completely different IDEs.

in Visual Studio, select the "Extension option" on the left menu bar or use short cut key Ctrl+Shift+X , you can add Oracle extension from there.


Can I ask what version of Visual Studio you are running here? Mine doesn't have that entire taskbar on the left side under "Extensions Marketplace".

Hi, the version of Visual studio is  : 1.86.2

This screenshot is from Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio. Also from the question, OP has already installed the ODT extension and does not need to add it again.
OP - The only thing I have found is from the view menu, click on Server Explorer. From the Server Explorer sidebar, ODT added a new connection type which allowed me to create a data connection to Oracle. That is all I've found so far and will post more if I find more. I'm in the same boat as there is no instructions to be found.

Judging from the comment OP left on the other answer, seems OP is using VS Code.
